# No speakable text present at Android Studio

Tags: java, android

When adding a field for entering a number(Number widget), the error "No speakable text present at Android Studio" takes off

[image: 1]

content_main.xml:

[image: 2]

activity_main.xml:

[image: 3]

Answer (score 26):

The problem is you are missing content labeling for the view, you should add content description so the user could simply understand what data he should enter into the view

for example, if you want the user to enter the number of cookies he wants you should add a content description as seen below:

```
android:contentDescription="Enter How Much Cookies You Want"
```

You should also add an android:hint so the user would have it in front of them an example of the data you want inputted for example:

```
android:hint="e.g 5"
```

So your views XML code should look as follows

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextNumber2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:minHeight="48dp"
    android:contentDescription="Enter How Much Cookies You Want" 
    android:hint="e.g 8" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I will consider

Comment: Adding a `contentDescription` for an `EditText` gives an error in Android 2022.3.1 (Android 11): `Editable text view with contentDescription`. Instead, only use the `hint` with a `@string` (to localize properly - otherwise there will be a "hardcoded text" warning).

Answer (score 3):

For everyone who has the same error message as above, but the shown solutions were not helpful, you could try the following: Check if there is an empty (not set) `android:contentDescription` field at any view in your *.xml file.

In my case I was adding an `android:contentDescription` to a view but forgot to actually set it's value - after I was setting up a string variable for it. So it looked like this:

```
<TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView_A"
                    android:text="@string/textView_A_text"
                    android:contentDescription=""/>
```

So Android Studio gave me the same "No speakable text present" error message, but not for that specific view but for another, which was some views below the one I changed, where I did not even added the field `android:contentDescription`.

After adding my string variable like in the following code, the error was gone.

```
<TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView_A"
                    android:text="@string/textView_A_text"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/TextView_A_contentDescription"/>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple you just need to add the text into the hint part.
search hint in search-bar ant type something in hint block.
and hit Enter.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just type in text view
android:contentDescription="NULL"
The error is gone example:-

```
 <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/delButton"
            android:layout_marginLeft="280dp"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/clear"
            android:contentDescription="NULL"

            />
```

[N.B= ImageButton and Textview same rule work properly]

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. Then I solved the problem by replacing androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout with LinearLayout and using android:hint.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Please write something"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -7):

The problem is missing constraints. Any view you add in **Constraint** layout, you must set the margins otherwise you will get those errors and even if your app managed to run, your edit text will not be place properly.

Add this to your editText;

```
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

Let me know if it worked.
Remember you can twick this to your desired position.

Comment: I updated the previous answer. Let me know if it solved the problem

Comment: Thanks, this solved the constraint error, but the error "No speakable text present" remained

Comment: Remove the two last attribute on EditText and remove Appbar behaviour as well on the Constraint layout if not necessary

Comment: And I will like to know... Do you get this error when the app is compilling or just at work time?