# i want to add a floatActionButton on android studio with java

Tags: java, android

when i add the FloatingActionButton using graphique methode the android stuio appears to me this error "floatbutnID <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton>: No speakable text present"

floatbutnID <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton>: No speakable text present how could correct this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speakable text is simply text that will be spoken by the system in phones for blind people. You can set it to "" if you don't need it.

This is the property for the speakable text

```
android:contentDescription="Your text"
```

You should look for information carefully before asking a question on Stack Overflow - it's in the rules of the forum. Please keep this in mind, otherwise you might get a bad reputation for duplicating questions.
I found the answer in 3 seconds in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69142705/no-speakable-text-present-at-android-studio) question

Answer (score 0):

if you are using xml, add `android:contentDescription="content description"` to the `floatingActionButton`  tag. or in Java `fab.setContentDescription(" content description")` `fab` is the name of your floatingActionButton.
example

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="content description"/>
```

Alternatively in Java

```
FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setContentDescription("content description");
```