# Cannot view the TabLayout and TabItems while designing the UI

Tags: android, xml, view, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

Tried to implement tab layout view, but nothing shows in the xml editor viewer after adding it.

I was able to put the tab layout tag and see it happen, but after adding the tab item tag nothing was visible, and further adding the view pager was also a problem to manage the constraint to it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFC107"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tab_chats"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Chats"/>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tab_status"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Status"/>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tab_Calls"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Calls"/>

    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tab_layout"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand you problem, sorry.
i have inserted your XML code in my android studio, and tablayout is visible.

maybe your problem isn't this?

[image]

Comment: How do I check what is the real problem?

Comment: it throws these 2 errors, 1. view_pager <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>: No speakable text present, 2. tab_layout <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>: No speakable text present, both almost look the same.

Comment: for error "no speakable text" see this stack-link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69142705/no-speakable-text-present-at-android-studio

Comment: Thanks @Paolino, I tried it previously didn't work.