# Tab Layout rendrer issue

Tags: android, android-layout

as soon as i am adding tab layout to my content_main.xml. its start giving error. No speakable text is present. Render Issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZevx.jpg)

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: try with this post:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69142705/no-speakable-text-present-at-android-studio